# What is the Best Way to store and Use the ID(Any one) in my application

Tags: android, performance

I know there are several ways of storing id's in application like 
  1) Session storage
  2) SQLITE
  3) Using Static Variables etc.
I want to Know which is the Best method for using and which will be the better way to increase the performance of my application.
Please help me out.Thank you

Comment: Just storing IDs won't have a performance impact on you application no matter what [storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) you use.

Comment: Thanks for reply awk ,I want to know which is better among all

Comment: Better in what way? This is primarily opinion based but I would suggest to use the shared preferences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well in my opiniion it is better to use session storage, for complex data it might be approprite to use SQLite but for id's only I think it would be better to use session storage.

Answer (score 1):

Go for the [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html), it is the most simple among them... I mean you could use SQL, but seems to be an overkill to go through all that hassle to store a simple ID.